# Unweighted bipartite $b$-Matching

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, time-complexity, matching

Consider the following problem, of which I am pretty certain that it is polynomially solvable.

Given some arbitrary bipartite Graph $G=(L\cup R,E)$ and some vector $b\in\mathbb{N}^{|L|}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{|L|} b(i)\geq|R|$ (so basically each "left" vertex gets some capacity which means it can at most match $b(i)$ vertices from the other side).

The question is: Is there a Matching such that each $v\in L$ gets matched at most $b(i)$ times **and** matches/covers each vertex $r\in R$ exactly once.

What algorithm could solve this in polynomial runtime? Can you
recommend some useful literature?

Comment: You may assume $b(i)\le|R|$. Split each left vertex $i$ into $b(i)$ copies, compute a maximum-cardinality matching, and check it has size $|R|$.

Comment: Or reduce to max flow with integer capacities.

Comment: This is not a research level question.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce to a flow problem: Split each left node into $L_i$ into two nodes $L_i$ and $L'_i$ connected with an edge with capacity $b(i)$ , give the orignal edges between left and right cpacity 1 and connect left side (the new split node) to super source and the right side to a super sync.
And solve max flow (can be done by repeatly finding shortest path and create reverse edges when allocating capacity which allows cancelling matching if it allows us to match more).